# How to set initial top position when an element's position attribute is sticky

Tags: css, css-position

I would love to set the initial position of `#box4` with a `top: 45px` just like the position of `#box3` relative to `#box2`, but still keep `#box4` with a `position: sticky` which makes it at the same level after scrolling down the page.

Initial position,

[image]

After scrolling,

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}

#box1 {
  position: static;
}

#box2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: -15px;
}

#box3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

#box4 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">
  B1 Static
</div>

<div class="box" id="box2">
  B2 Relative
</div>

<div class="box" id="box3">
  B3 Fixed
</div>

<div class="box" id="box4">
  B4 Sticky
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible work around is to use a negative margin-top to position the `#box4` into the right place.

```
#box4 {
  margin: -15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  left: 150px;
}
```